# The method sort(LineItem.FullLineItemComparator) is undefined for the type List<LineItem>

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting

I'm rebuilding some code in Java 6. For the following I get a warning with red-underline in Eclipse:

```
List<LineItem> lineItemList = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
lineItemList.sort(new LineItem.FullLineItemComparator());
```

`The method sort(LineItem.FullLineItemComparator) is undefined for the type List<LineItem>`

At. `.sort(...` Eclipse recommends:

`((Object) lineItemList).sort(new LineItem.FullLineItemComparator());`

This doesn't remove the warning and the code does not compile.

**FullLineItemComparator:**

```
static class FullLineItemComparator implements Comparator<LineItem>

    {
        public int compare(LineItem c1, LineItem c2)
        {
            int result;
            result = c1.initials.compareTo(c2.initials);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }

            result = c1.date.compareTo(c2.date);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }

            result = c1.timeStart.compareTo(c2.timeStart);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }

            result = c1.timeEnd.compareTo(c2.timeEnd);
            if (result != 0) {
                return -result;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Do you see anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way how to sort a list from JCF in java is to use a static method in Collections.

```
Collections.sort(lineItemList, new LineItem.FullLineItemComparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` method of `List` was added in Java 8, it does not exist in Java 6.

In Java 6 you can use `Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(lineItemList, new LineItem.FullLineItemComparator());
```